# Find all common elements in two lists

Tags: java, string, list, date, arraylist

I am trying to find the common elements in my ArrayList "list1"

```
List<LocalDate> list1 = new ArrayList<> ();
for (LocalDate d = dateFrom; !d.isAfter(dateTo); d = d.plusDays(1)) {
      dates.add(d);
```

that consists of all dates between "dateFrom" and "dateTo" and my list "list2"

```
List<LocalDate> list2 = Arrays.asList(dateTime);
```

where dateTime is a variable that stores only the dates from a textfile with the following structure:

```
1946-01-12;07:00:00;-1.3;G
1946-01-12;13:00:00;0.3;G
1946-01-12;18:00:00;-2.8;G
1946-01-13;07:00:00;-6.2;G
1946-01-13;13:00:00;-4.7;G
1946-01-13;18:00:00;-4.3;G
```

I tried using `list2.retainAll(list1);` in order to find all the dates in list2 that is also in list1, but I think my problem is that list2 is not an arraylist. How can I fix that?

```
private static List<WeatherDataHandler> weatherData = new ArrayList<>();
public void loadData(String filePath) throws IOException {
//Read all data
    List<String> fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filePath"));

    Map<String, Long> frequencyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    LocalDate dateFrom = LocalDate.of(1946,01,12);
    LocalDate dateTo = LocalDate.of(1946, 01, 14);

    List<LocalDate> list1 = new ArrayList<> ();
    for (LocalDate d = dateFrom; !d.isAfter(dateTo); d = d.plusDays(1)) {
      dates.add(d);

    }

    for(String str : fileData) {
        List<String> parsed = parseData(str);
        LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(parsed.get(0));
        LocalTime Time = LocalTime.parse(parsed.get(1));
        double temperature = Double.parseDouble(parsed.get(2));
        String tag = parsed.get(3);

        WeatherDataHandler weather = new WeatherDataHandler(dateTime, Time, temperature, tag);
        weatherData.add(weather);

        List<LocalDate> list2 = Arrays.asList(dateTime);

        list2.retainAll(list1); 

        String strDate = list2.toString();
        frequencyMap.compute(strDate,
                (date, count) -> count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : frequencyMap
            .entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() < 24){
        System.out.println(
                entry.getKey() + ": " + (24-entry.getValue()));
    }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - your code shows `list2` being an empty list, so what would there be to retain?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans list2 should not be empty, it consits of the elements in dateTime which is all the dates from the textfile.

Comment: What is the expected output, and what you getting instead?

Comment: @VivinPaliath My expected output from the whole code is a list with all the elements in list2 that is contained in list1, and then I want to count the frequency of all dates and print it.

Comment: I understand that -- what are you getting instead right now?

Comment: @VivinPaliath After implementing Arvind's suggestion I get: "[1946-01-12]: 21
[1946-01-13]: 21
[1946-01-14]: 21
[]: 23" so now I just want to find out how to not get any empty elements like the last one

Comment: @Natalie_94 - I've posted an update. I hope, it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
List<LocalDate> commonList = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
for (LocalDate date : list1) {
    if(list2.contains(date)) {
        commonList.add(date);
    }
}
System.out.println("Common elements: " + commonList)
```

**[Update]**

Replace

```
if (entry.getValue() < 24)
```

with

```
if (entry.getValue() < 24 && !entry.getKey().equals("[]"))
```

in your code to get rid of something like `[]: 23`.

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how to not return [] when elements are not common? Like the last one of these: Common elements: [1946-01-14]
Common elements: [1946-01-14]
Common elements: []

Comment: Do you want to return common elements or the elements of `list2` which are not in `list1`?

Comment: I want to return common elements like you did, but I do not want to return these: "Common elements: []" like empty space, when elements are not common